# Can I combine voltages of the power supply?

Tags: power-supply

Super entry level here.
Forgive my very basic question.

I have this starter circuit:

[image]

I'm sure you're all familiar with this one, in which I set up 5V on the left jumper, and 3.3V on the right jumper.

Can I set up a circuit in which I can get 8.3V by combining the two voltages together?

I'm afraid to test any circuit and fry the power supply.

Bonus question: There are extra 5V and 3.3V jumpers (below the white power switch in the picture.)

If my question is doable, does that mean I can potentially have 2x8.3 = 16.6V?  How would that setup go?

Comment: If you just need a higher voltage for something, you might be able to connect to the unregulated input voltage on the filter capacitor. It will probably be at least 7 volts and perhaps as high as 9 or 10 volts. This will depend on the voltage of the input source, which looks like a simple "wall-wart", and it will also vary with load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the voltages can't be added because the negative supply terminals of both voltages are already the shared 0V common ground terminal.

You have both 5V and 3.3V only, nothing else.

To be fair, there is a third theoretical option to connect a load between 5V and 3.3V, to get a 1.7V output, but in practice, it might not work and it can even damage the 3.3V regulator as they usually can't sink current, so it is not recommended to try that.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't really looking for more voltage or anything -- I just thought that as a question, and its answer would've been something to learn from. Thank you, again.